# segmentation fault core dumped in pqueue heap based before dequeuing caused only by very large random inputs

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, priority-queue

Hello I am following CS106b programming abstractions from Stanford which is a programing course taught in c++ and in the PQueue assignment  (priority queue )( the heap based implementation) I  have this segmentation fault core dumped behavior, when dequeuing stuff from a pqueue into which i have enquired large number of entries of random nature, the exact amount needed for it vary from run to run and it can be anything between 10000 to 70000 entries, the problem does not occur in case when i have enqueued sorted input, like lupe counter, it can be even 10000000 entries. I have spent some hours trying to find the bug but i can not find it my guess is that i have to do something wrong with memory management but the PQueue::doubleCapacity() method i use i have based on one from working vector class, i think the enqueuing and dequeuing methods are fine because the pqueue works as it should for still quite large entries (less than 10000). It is not the sort of question which can be easily googled so pleas help the code is below. the code uses some clases from CS106 libraries which can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/progabstrlib/ but i hope that it is simple enough so you do not need to compile it to tell me what I am doing wrong.

i am working on Ubuntu 12.04 using g++ if that is important

```
/*
 * File: pqueue.h
 */

#ifndef _pqueue_h
#define _pqueue_h

#include "genlib.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "disallowcopy.h"

class PQueue
{
  public:
    PQueue();
    ~PQueue();
    bool isEmpty();
    int size();
    void enqueue(int newElem);
    int dequeueMax();
    /*
     * needed for assigment puprposses there are three more PQueue implementation
     * so it is needed to compare memory speed trade of.
     */
    int bytesUsed();
    string implementationName();
    void printDebuggingInfo();
    bool printDebugToFile(string fileName);

  private:
    template <typename Type>
void PrintArry(Type arr[], int size);
DISALLOW_COPYING(PQueue)
static const int START_SIZE = 2;
int* entries;
int _capacity_, _size_;
void doubleCapacity();
void halfCapacity();
void swap(int& one, int &two);
};
#endif

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
 * File: pqheap.cpp
 * --    ----------------
 */

//#include "pqueue.h"  // commented out so i can compile this whole file at once
#include "genlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

PQueue::PQueue()
{
    entries = new int[START_SIZE];
    _capacity_ = START_SIZE;
    _size_ =  0;
    /*
     * i am not using first cell so i want to know what should be in it this is because of
     * the fact that in the way in which i have implemented heap based PQueue the acuall values
     * are stored form number 1 and not 0; so child of value x can be reach by multiplying
     * the index of it by two adding 1 for the second child;
     */
    entries[_size_] = -888;
}

PQueue::~PQueue()
{
    if (entries != NULL) delete[] entries;
}

bool PQueue::isEmpty()
{
    return (_size_ == 0);
}

int PQueue::size()
{
    return _size_;
}

/*
 * the heap enqueuing works by adding new value to the end of the array and bubrling it up to the
 * wright position by compare with its parent and swap if necesery.
 */
void PQueue::enqueue(int newValue)
{
    int curValPos = ++_size_;
    if(_size_ == _capacity_)
        doubleCapacity();
    entries[curValPos] = newValue;

    // bubbling value up to its proper position;
    while(curValPos > 1)
    {
        int parentPos = curValPos/2;
        if(newValue < entries[parentPos])
            break;
        else
        {
            swap(entries[curValPos], entries[parentPos]);
            curValPos = parentPos;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * dequeuing is done by taking the highest value ( value from index 1 ) and then to repare the
 * queue last value is copied to the first position and then buubled down till it reaches
 * its proper position, it is done by comparison with children of the current position and
 * swaping while nesessery.
 */
int PQueue::dequeueMax()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        Error("Tried to dequeue max from an empty pqueue!");
    if(_capacity_ > (_size_*2)+10)
        halfCapacity();
    int curPos = 1;
    int maxValue = entries[curPos];
    //cout << maxValue << "|" ;
    entries[curPos] = entries[_size_];

    _size_ -= 1;
    int biggerChild = 0;

    while(biggerChild < _size_)
    {
        biggerChild = curPos*2;
        if(entries[biggerChild] < entries[biggerChild+1])
            biggerChild += 1; // the second child is bigger than the first
        // if the bigger child is smaller than newVal or if the current
        // position does not have children
        if(entries[curPos] >= entries[biggerChild] || biggerChild > _size_)
            break;
        else
        {
            swap(entries[curPos], entries[biggerChild]);
            curPos = biggerChild;
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

int PQueue::bytesUsed()
{
    cout << endl << "______________________ " << endl;
    cout << "SIZE OF THIS = " << sizeof(*this) << endl;
    cout << "SIZE OF ENTRIES = " << sizeof(*entries) << endl;
    cout << "______________________ " << endl;
    return sizeof(*this) + sizeof(int)*_size_;
}


string PQueue::implementationName()
{
    return "( heap )";
}

void PQueue::printDebuggingInfo()
{
    cout << "------------------ START DEBUG INFO ------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Pqueue contains " << _size_ << " entries" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= _size_; i++)
        cout << entries[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;

    /*
     * the print out is helpful only for the top few nodes and children.
     */
    int numInCurRow = 1 , numInPrewRow = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= _size_; i++)
        {
            cout << entries[i] << "|";
            numInCurRow--;
            if(numInCurRow == 0)
            {
                cout << endl;
                numInPrewRow *= 2;
                numInCurRow = numInPrewRow;
            }
        }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------ END DEBUG INFO ------------------" << endl;
}

bool PQueue::printDebugToFile(string fileName)
{
    ofstream outFile;
    string str = fileName;
    outFile.open(str.c_str());
    if(outFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "WriteVectorToFile could not open file " + fileName << endl;
        return false;
    }
    outFile << "------------------ START DEBUG INFO ------------------" << endl;
    outFile << "Pqueue contains " << _size_ << " entries" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= _size_; i++)
        outFile << entries[i] << " ";
    outFile << endl << endl;

    int numInCurRow = 1 , numInPrewRow = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= _size_; i++)
        {
            outFile << entries[i] << "|";
            numInCurRow--;
            if(numInCurRow == 0)
            {
                outFile << endl;
                numInPrewRow *= 2;
                numInCurRow = numInPrewRow;
            }
        }
        outFile << endl;
        outFile << "------------------ END DEBUG INFO ------------------" << endl;

        outFile.close();
    return true;

}

void PQueue::doubleCapacity()
{
    _capacity_ *= 2;
    int* biggerArry = new int[_capacity_];
    cout << "resizing capacity from " << _capacity_/2 << "  new capacity = " << _capacity_ << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i <= _size_; i++)
        biggerArry[i] = entries[i];
    delete[] entries;
    entries = biggerArry;

}

/*
 *
 */
void PQueue::halfCapacity()
{
    _capacity_ /= 2;
    int* halfArry = new int[_capacity_];
    cout << endl <<" downsizing capacity from " << _capacity_*2 << "  new capacity = " << _capacity_ << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < _capacity_; i++)
        halfArry[i] = entries[i];
    delete[] entries;
    entries = halfArry;
}


void PQueue::swap(int &one, int &two)
{
    int tmp = one;
    one = two;
    two = tmp;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * main.cpp the driver
 */

/* File: main.cpp
 * --------------
 * Simple main module for PQueue assignment.
 */

//#include "pqheap.cpp"  // commented out so i can compile this whole file at once
#include <iostream>
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "random.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include "vector.h"
using namespace std;

/*
 * auxiliary functions
 */
string iToS(int x);
int sToI(string str);

bool ReadVectorFromFile(Vector<int> &v, string fileName);

template <typename Type>
bool WriteVectorToFile(Vector<Type> v, string fileName);



int main()
{
    Randomize();
    PQueue pq;

    while(true)
    {

        cout << "how big queue do we want to work with ? "+pq.implementationName() << endl;
        int y, x = GetInteger();
        Vector <int> v;

        /*
         * "1000000.vec" file contains 1000000 unsorted integers with no repetitions,
         * use of it produces the same segmentation fault core dumped it is cometed out for now
         */
        //ReadVectorFromFile(v,"1000000.vec");

        double start = double(clock())/1000000;
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            pq.enqueue(RandomInteger(0,i));
        }

        double stop = double(clock())/1000000;
        cout << "time needed for enqueue of size "<< x << " = " << stop-start << endl;

        //v.clear();
        pq.printDebugToFile("debug."+ iToS(x)+ ".debug");

        /*
         * it seems that even dequeung a few values from the top produces the error
         */
        cout << "how much to dequeue ?" << endl;
        y = GetInteger();
        start = double(clock())/1000000;
        for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            //pq.printDebuggingInfo();
            v.add(pq.dequeueMax());
        }
        stop = double(clock())/1000000;
        cout << "time needed for dequeue "+iToS(y)+" elements from PQ of size "<< x << " = " << stop-start << endl;

        WriteVectorToFile(v, "QUEUE_" + iToS(x) + ".test");
    }

    return (0);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

string iToS(int x)
{
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << x;
    return convert.str();
}

int sToI(string str)
{
    istringstream converter(str);
    int n;
    converter >> n;
    return n;
}

bool ReadVectorFromFile(Vector<int> &v, string fileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    if(inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << " ReadVectorFromFile could not read from the file " + fileName << endl;
        return false;
    }
    string line;
    while(true)
    {
        getline(inFile, line);
        if(inFile.fail())
            break;
        v.add(sToI(line));
    }
    inFile.close();
    return true;
}

template <typename Longboard>
bool WriteVectorToFile(Vector<Longboard> v, string fileName)
{
    ofstream outFile;
    string str = fileName;
    outFile.open(str.c_str());
    if(outFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "WriteVectorToFile could not open file " + fileName << endl;
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        outFile << v[i];
        outFile << endl;
    }
    outFile.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please narrow it down! I suggest you use a debugger to find the location of the crash, and then edit your question to only include the relevant code.

Comment: And if it seems random, then you're probably invoking _undefined behavior_, probably by writing out of bounds of allocated memory, or using pointers to variables local to functions which have returned.

Comment: Thank you Joachim after your comment i actually have found the bug and it was indeed accessing unallocated memory due to faulty logic in break condition in dequeuing in the loop which repairs the heap after dequeuing,  it was trying to compare value at current position with value at  far far away child node which was far out of bounds and should be prevented, now it is thanks.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , would you please put your comment as an answer to be accepted so this question can be marked as "answered"

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, your use of `<= _size_` looks suspicious. It seems like `_size_` represents the number of elements in the queue, [0, _capacity]. Therefore, the index of the last element should be `_size_ - 1`

Keep in mind though, you'll have to make sure you check `isEmpty()` before you index `[_size_-1]`, just in case `_size_` is 0.